# Can't move a node from one state tree to another. If this is intentional, first remove the node from its current state tree by calling removeFromTree

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin22

When I log in from two accounts to my vaadin app I get this error message

> Can't move a node from one state tree to another. If this is
> intentional, first remove the node from its current state tree by
> calling removeFromTree

Learn more about calling the error:
Logging in with Google OAuth2
When logging in to the application from user A's account, everything works fine, as soon as I log in to the application from user B's account at the same time, I get an error message

As I understand from the message, I have common interface objects that I have to clean up or create new ones for each incoming user

Maybe there is some tutorial on implementing an application that is used by several users at the same time or something similar?

Comment: Do you use `@PreserveOnRefresh`? Are you 100% certain, that you are not sharing components beyond UI-scope?  This could be a `static` in a class, or spring components  with singleton or session scope.

Comment: hey @cfrick 
you're right, I removed the static component, how it works 
but I suspect that I should familiarize myself with Vaadin Spring Scopus, or is my problem unrelated to this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Vaadin does not allow sharing components.  This is true inside a single
UI state tree (the component will be *moved* instead of being visible on
two locations).

And this is especially true for sharing components between *different*
UI state trees.  The result is the error you got there.

Prime suspects for (accidentally) sharing components are:

- singleton patterns, `static` variables, or things, that are only there
  once, like `enum`s; usually things, developers only want to keep one
  thing around or "save" resources (e.g.  don't put
  `VaadinIcons.COGS.create()` in your `enum`.  Just use
  `VaadinIcons.COGS` and then call the `.create()` on it, whenever you
  add one to the UI.
- Spring (or other DI) singleton, session, ... scoped things. Make sure
  to check out the [docs about the Spring
  scopes](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/integrations/spring/scopes);
  usually everything "under" `@UIScope` should be fine (this also
  includes "harmless" scopes like `prototype`.

Note also, that the problem is always with the *component*, not with
what the component itself uses outside of other components.  So it's OK
to have a prototype:d `TextField` using a singleton `I18NService`.

Those kind of errors are quite sneaky, since developers tend to only
ever test with one session/UI and tend to creep up once the app goes
live.  And the given error message is practically useless outside an
application with a debugger attached to it.

Comment: Excellent answer. The root of the problem is that moving a component from one UI to another causes the component to silently disappear in the former UI, thus causing a hard-to-reproduce strange behavior. This exception was designed to prevent that, but the message was just horrible. Hopefully this PR improves things: https://github.com/vaadin/flow/pull/18019