# vaadin java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't move a node from one state tree to another

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

Try try use latest vaadin framework (23.2) and @PreserveOnRefresh for main route. I receive subject exception.
I read this question and answers [Can't move a node from one state tree to another. If this is intentional, first remove the node from its current state tree by calling removeFromTree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72819037/cant-move-a-node-from-one-state-tree-to-another-if-this-is-intentional-first)
But i don't have shared static resources and don't use Spring. For DI use CDI addon. I also read that the Dialog component can also affect this. (May better use new free ConfirmDialog?)
My stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't move a node from one state tree to another. If this is intentional, first remove the node from its current state tree by calling removeFromTree
        at com.vaadin.flow.internal.StateNode.doSetTree(StateNode.java:739)
        at com.vaadin.flow.internal.StateNode.lambda$setTree$3(StateNode.java:380)
        at com.vaadin.flow.internal.StateNode.visitNodeTree(StateNode.java:688)
        at com.vaadin.flow.internal.StateNode.setTree(StateNode.java:380)
        at com.vaadin.flow.internal.StateNode.setParent(StateNode.java:274)
        at com.vaadin.flow.internal.nodefeature.NodeFeature.attachPotentialChild(NodeFeature.java:80)
        at com.vaadin.flow.internal.nodefeature.StateNodeNodeList.add(StateNodeNodeList.java:55)
        at com.vaadin.flow.internal.nodefeature.ElementChildrenList.add(ElementChildrenList.java:44)
        at com.vaadin.flow.dom.impl.AbstractNodeStateProvider.insertChild(AbstractNodeStateProvider.java:104)
        at com.vaadin.flow.dom.Node.insertChild(Node.java:386)
        at com.vaadin.flow.dom.Node.appendChild(Node.java:163)
        at com.vaadin.flow.dom.Node.appendChild(Node.java:147)
        at com.vaadin.flow.component.internal.JavaScriptBootstrapUI$JavaScriptUIInternalUpdater.updateRoot(JavaScriptBootstrapUI.java:422)
        at com.vaadin.flow.component.internal.UIInternals.showRouteTarget(UIInternals.java:764)
        at com.vaadin.flow.router.internal.AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.handle(AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.java:222)
        at com.vaadin.flow.component.internal.JavaScriptNavigationStateRenderer.handle(JavaScriptNavigationStateRenderer.java:78)
        at com.vaadin.flow.router.internal.AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.lambda$getPreservedChain$cdbeaece$1(AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.java:778)
        at com.vaadin.flow.component.page.Page.lambda$retrieveExtendedClientDetails$fc941a8c$1(Page.java:576)
        at com.vaadin.flow.component.internal.PendingJavaScriptInvocation.complete(PendingJavaScriptInvocation.java:96)
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.UidlWriter.lambda$createReturnValueChannel$d9004ac5$1(UidlWriter.java:316)
        at com.vaadin.flow.internal.nodefeature.ReturnChannelMap.lambda$registerChannel$2a20409b$1(ReturnChannelMap.java:124)
        at com.vaadin.flow.internal.nodefeature.ReturnChannelMap$ChannelImpl.invoke(ReturnChannelMap.java:74)
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ReturnChannelHandler.handleNode(ReturnChannelHandler.java:78)
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.rpc.AbstractRpcInvocationHandler.handle(AbstractRpcInvocationHandler.java:75)
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocationData(ServerRpcHandler.java:438)
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.lambda$handleInvocations$1(ServerRpcHandler.java:419)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocations(ServerRpcHandler.java:419)
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:320)
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:115)
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:40)
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1564)
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:364)
        at com.vaadin.cdi.CdiVaadinServlet.service(CdiVaadinServlet.java:67)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve.invoke(RewriteValve.java:289)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:888)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1597)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
16:21:58.739 [https-jsse-nio-443-exec-13] DEBUG c.v.f.s.communication.UidlWriter - * Creating response to client
16:21:58.740 [https-jsse-nio-443-exec-13] DEBUG com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService - Removing closed UI 1
```

In what direction to look?

Thanks!

Comment: This exception means that the same instance of a component is already present in another UI. Are you storing components in static variables or using singleton scope when injecting components?

Comment: Hi Markus. No. I don't use components in static variables and don't use Singleton annotations for beans. Only ApplicationScoped for services. All beans injected through Inject annotation. Is there a legal way to find out where the problematic place is?

Comment: I still believe it has to do with dependency scoping. With preserveOnRefresh, Vaadin creates a new UI instance under the hood. CDI default scope is Dependent, I think something is not going right here. Does it work if you remove the PreserveOnRefresh?

Comment: Yes. If i remove PreserveOnRefresh i don't get this error

Comment: TBH, it is a little vague without seeing your code. Could you add a [MCVE]?