# Can't move a node from one state tree to another ERROR with Vaadin23

Tags: java, jetty, vaadin23, vaadin-session

I'm developing a simple application based on Vaadin 23 – Plain Java.

For the SessionManagement I created a class named AppServlet

```
public class AppServlet extends VaadinServlet implements  SessionInitListener, SessionDestroyListener{...}
```

When I click on the logout button, these method are called:

```
 UI.getCurrent().getPage().setLocation("login");
 VaadinSession.getCurrent().getSession().invalidate();
 VaadinSession.getCurrent().close();
```

It seems to work well but if I try to re-login I get this error

```
ERROR com.vaadin.flow.router.InternalServerError - There was an exception while trying to navigate to 'home'
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't move a node from one state tree to another. If this is intentional, first remove the node from its current state tree by calling removeFromTree
    at com.vaadin.flow.internal.StateNode.doSetTree(StateNode.java:739)
    at com.vaadin.flow.internal.StateNode.lambda$setTree$3(StateNode.java:380)
    at com.vaadin.flow.internal.StateNode.visitNodeTree(StateNode.java:688)
    at com.vaadin.flow.internal.StateNode.setTree(StateNode.java:380)
    at com.vaadin.flow.internal.StateNode.setParent(StateNode.java:274)
    at com.vaadin.flow.internal.nodefeature.NodeFeature.attachPotentialChild(NodeFeature.java:80)
    at com.vaadin.flow.internal.nodefeature.StateNodeNodeList.add(StateNodeNodeList.java:55)
    at com.vaadin.flow.internal.nodefeature.ElementChildrenList.add(ElementChildrenList.java:44)
    at com.vaadin.flow.dom.impl.AbstractNodeStateProvider.insertChild(AbstractNodeStateProvider.java:104)
    at com.vaadin.flow.dom.Node.insertChild(Node.java:386)
    at com.vaadin.flow.dom.Node.appendChild(Node.java:163)
    at com.vaadin.flow.dom.Node.appendChild(Node.java:147)
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.internal.JavaScriptBootstrapUI$JavaScriptUIInternalUpdater.updateRoot(JavaScriptBootstrapUI.java:427)
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.internal.UIInternals.showRouteTarget(UIInternals.java:769)
    at com.vaadin.flow.router.internal.AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.handle(AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.java:231)
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.internal.JavaScriptNavigationStateRenderer.handle(JavaScriptNavigationStateRenderer.java:78)
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.internal.JavaScriptBootstrapUI.handleNavigation(JavaScriptBootstrapUI.java:322)
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.internal.JavaScriptBootstrapUI.navigate(JavaScriptBootstrapUI.java:230)
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.UI.navigate(UI.java:1101)
    at it.datariver.app.views.login.LoginView.lambda$buildLoginButton$e3c5ac47$1(LoginView.java:106)
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.ComponentEventBus.fireEventForListener(ComponentEventBus.java:233)
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.ComponentEventBus.handleDomEvent(ComponentEventBus.java:475)
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.ComponentEventBus.lambda$addDomTrigger$dd1b7957$1(ComponentEventBus.java:292)
    at com.vaadin.flow.internal.nodefeature.ElementListenerMap.lambda$fireEvent$2(ElementListenerMap.java:447)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at com.vaadin.flow.internal.nodefeature.ElementListenerMap.fireEvent(ElementListenerMap.java:447)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.rpc.EventRpcHandler.handleNode(EventRpcHandler.java:62)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.rpc.AbstractRpcInvocationHandler.handle(AbstractRpcInvocationHandler.java:75)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocationData(ServerRpcHandler.java:438)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.lambda$handleInvocations$1(ServerRpcHandler.java:419)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocations(ServerRpcHandler.java:419)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:320)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:115)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:40)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1564)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:369)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:764)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$ChainEnd.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1665)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.servlet.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter(WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:170)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:527)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:578)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1570)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1383)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:484)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1543)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1305)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:563)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$0(HttpChannel.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:762)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:314)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectableChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectableChannelEndPoint.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.runTask(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:416)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.consumeTask(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:385)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.tryProduce(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:272)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.lambda$new$0(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:934)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1078)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Do someone know how to solve it?
Thanks in advance
Luca

Comment: This exception happens when Vaadin tries to attach a component to UI which is already attached somewhere else. This most likely means that you have component as static variable or wrong scope, hence instance is being reused when it shouldn't.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't move a node from one state tree to another. If this is intentional, first remove the node from its current state tree by calling removeFromTree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72819037/cant-move-a-node-from-one-state-tree-to-another-if-this-is-intentional-first)

Comment: yes, thank you, it was a similar issue.