# Can't move a node from one state tree to another - Spring Error

Tags: spring, dependencies, vaadin, inversion-of-control, code-injection

I made a simple Vaadin Web Programm implementing the Spring Framework.
When i refresh the page i keep getting the Error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't move a node from one state tree to another. If this is intentional, first remove the node from its current state tree by calling removeFromTree
> at com.vaadin.flow.internal.StateNode.doSetTree(StateNode.java:739) ~[flow-server-23.3.3.jar:23.3.3]
> at com.vaadin.flow.internal.StateNode.lambda$setTree$3(StateNode.java:380) ~[flow-server-23.3.3.jar:23.3.3]
> at com.vaadin.flow.internal.StateNode.visitNodeTree(StateNode.java:688) ~[flow-server-23.3.3.jar:23.3.3]
> at com.vaadin.flow.internal.StateNode.setTree(StateNode.java:380) ~[flow-server-23.3.3.jar:23.3.3]
> at com.vaadin.flow.internal.StateNode.setParent(StateNode.java:274) ~[flow-server-23.3.3.jar:23.3.3]
> at com.vaadin.flow.internal.nodefeature.NodeFeature.attachPotentialChild(NodeFeature.java:80) ~[flow-server-23.3.3.jar:23.3.3]
> at com.vaadin.flow.internal.nodefeature.StateNodeNodeList.add(StateNodeNodeList.java:55) ~[flow-server-23.3.3.jar:23.3.3]
> at com.vaadin.flow.internal.nodefeature.ElementChildrenList.add(ElementChildrenList.java:44) ~[flow-server-23.3.3.jar:23.3.3]
> at com.vaadin.flow.dom.impl.AbstractNodeStateProvider.insertChild(AbstractNodeStateProvider.java:104) ~[flow-server-23.3.3.jar:23.3.3]
> at com.vaadin.flow.dom.Node.insertChild(Node.java:386) ~[flow-server-23.3.3.jar:23.3.3]
> at com.vaadin.flow.dom.Node.appendChild(Node.java:163) ~[flow-server-23.3.3.jar:23.3.3]
> at com.vaadin.flow.dom.Node.appendChild(Node.java:147) ~[flow-server-23.3.3.jar:23.3.3]
> at com.vaadin.flow.component.internal.JavaScriptBootstrapUI$JavaScriptUIInternalUpdater.updateRoot(JavaScriptBootstrapUI.java:427) ~[flow-server-23.3.3.jar:23.3.3]
> at com.vaadin.flow.component.internal.UIInternals.showRouteTarget(UIInternals.java:769) ~[flow-server-23.3.3.jar:23.3.3]
> at com.vaadin.flow.router.internal.AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.handle(AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.java:231) ~[flow-server-23.3.3.jar:23.3.3]
> at com.vaadin.flow.component.internal.JavaScriptNavigationStateRenderer.handle(JavaScriptNavigationStateRenderer.java:78) ~[flow-server-23.3.3.jar:23.3.3]
> at com.vaadin.flow.component.internal.JavaScriptBootstrapUI.handleNavigation(JavaScriptBootstrapUI.java:322) ~[flow-server-23.3.3.jar:23.3.3]
> at com.vaadin.flow.component.internal.JavaScriptBootstrapUI.renderViewForRoute(JavaScriptBootstrapUI.java:285) ~[flow-server-23.3.3.jar:23.3.3]
> at com.vaadin.flow.component.internal.JavaScriptBootstrapUI.connectClient(JavaScriptBootstrapUI.java:151) ~[flow-server-23.3.3.jar:23.3.3]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
> at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.rpc.PublishedServerEventHandlerRpcHandler.invokeMethod(PublishedServerEventHandlerRpcHandler.java:222) ~[flow-server-23.3.3.jar:23.3.3]
> at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.rpc.PublishedServerEventHandlerRpcHandler.invokeMethod(PublishedServerEventHandlerRpcHandler.java:199) ~[flow-server-23.3.3.jar:23.3.3]
> at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.rpc.PublishedServerEventHandlerRpcHandler.invokeMethod(PublishedServerEventHandlerRpcHandler.java:149) ~[flow-server-23.3.3.jar:23.3.3]
> at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.rpc.PublishedServerEventHandlerRpcHandler.handleNode(PublishedServerEventHandlerRpcHandler.java:132) ~[flow-server-23.3.3.jar:23.3.3]
> at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.rpc.AbstractRpcInvocationHandler.handle(AbstractRpcInvocationHandler.java:75) ~[flow-server-23.3.3.jar:23.3.3]
> at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocationData(ServerRpcHandler.java:438) ~[flow-server-23.3.3.jar:23.3.3]
> at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.lambda$handleInvocations$1(ServerRpcHandler.java:419) ~[flow-server-23.3.3.jar:23.3.3]
> at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511) ~[na:na]
> at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocations(ServerRpcHandler.java:419) ~[flow-server-23.3.3.jar:23.3.3]
> at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:320) ~[flow-server-23.3.3.jar:23.3.3]
> at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:115) ~[flow-server-23.3.3.jar:23.3.3]
> at com.vaadin.flow.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:40) ~[flow-server-23.3.3.jar:23.3.3]
> at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1564) ~[flow-server-23.3.3.jar:23.3.3]
> at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:369) ~[flow-server-23.3.3.jar:23.3.3]
> at com.vaadin.flow.spring.SpringServlet.service(SpringServlet.java:106) ~[vaadin-spring-23.3.3.jar:na]
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:779) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:4.0.FR]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:711) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:353) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:313) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletForwardingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletForwardingController.java:141) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:51) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1071) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:964) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:696) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:4.0.FR]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:779) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:4.0.FR]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
> at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:177) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.__invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:41002) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
> at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
> at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
> at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
> at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:891) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1784) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]

My Code:
**MainView**

```
@Route(value = "test")
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout {
    private final Button button;
    private final TextField textField;
    public MainView (Button button, TextField textField) {
        this.button = button;
        this.textField = textField;
        doSomething();
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        if(button!=null && textField!=null) {
            add(button);
            add(new Paragraph(textField));
        }
        else Notification.show("Error");
    }
}
```

**AppConfig**

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    public Button returnNewButton() {
        Button b = new Button();
        b.getStyle().set("height", "50px").set("width", "150px");
        b.addThemeVariants(ButtonVariant.LUMO_PRIMARY);
        return b;
    }

    @Bean
    public TextField returnNewTextField() {
        return new TextField("Input");
    }
}
```

Already tried to use different @Scope types but still doesnt work.

Im new to Spring, what did i made wrong here with the dependency injection?
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't move a node from one state tree to another. If this is intentional, first remove the node from its current state tree by calling removeFromTree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72819037/cant-move-a-node-from-one-state-tree-to-another-if-this-is-intentional-first)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should in general not inject UI components, you should create them in the view. In your case you are creating a singleton button that is reused across all views. This won't work as a component instance can only be used in one place.