# Vaadin throws an exception in Tomcat log on page refresh

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, vaadin23

I had my Vaadin application deployed on Tomcat and it was working for me for about an hour.
Then it stopped working for unknown reason. When refreshing the page I am getting only page background and in catalina logs exception stack trace appears.

> 2023-03-10 05:21:32.343 ERROR 124726 --- [nio-8080-exec-8]
> c.v.flow.router.InternalServerError      : There was an exception
> while trying to navigate to ''
>
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't move a node from one state tree
> to another. If this is intentional, first remove the node from its
> current state tree by calling removeFromTree  at
> com.vaadin.flow.internal.StateNode.doSetTree(StateNode.java:739)
> ~[flow-server-23.3.4.jar:23.3.4]  at
> com.vaadin.flow.internal.StateNode.lambda$setTree$3(StateNode.java:380)
> ~[flow-server-23.3.4.jar:23.3.4]  at
> com.vaadin.flow.internal.StateNode.visitNodeTree(StateNode.java:688)
> ~[flow-server-23.3.4.jar:23.3.4]  at
> com.vaadin.flow.internal.StateNode.setTree(StateNode.java:380)
> ~[flow-server-23.3.4.jar:23.3.4]  at
> com.vaadin.flow.internal.StateNode.setParent(StateNode.java:274)
> ~[flow-server-23.3.4.jar:23.3.4]  at
> com.vaadin.flow.internal.nodefeature.NodeFeature.attachPotentialChild(NodeFeature.java:80)
> ~[flow-server-23.3.4.jar:23.3.4]  at
> com.vaadin.flow.internal.nodefeature.StateNodeNodeList.add(StateNodeNodeList.java:55)
> ~[flow-server-23.3.4.jar:23.3.4]  at
> com.vaadin.flow.internal.nodefeature.ElementChildrenList.add(ElementChildrenList.java:44)
> ~[flow-server-23.3.4.jar:23.3.4]  at
> com.vaadin.flow.dom.impl.AbstractNodeStateProvider.insertChild(AbstractNodeStateProvider.java:104)
> ~[flow-server-23.3.4.jar:23.3.4]  at
> com.vaadin.flow.dom.Node.insertChild(Node.java:386)
> ~[flow-server-23.3.4.jar:23.3.4]  at
> com.vaadin.flow.dom.Node.appendChild(Node.java:163)
> ~[flow-server-23.3.4.jar:23.3.4]  at
> com.vaadin.flow.dom.Node.appendChild(Node.java:147)
> ~[flow-server-23.3.4.jar:23.3.4]  at
> com.vaadin.flow.component.internal.JavaScriptBootstrapUI$JavaScriptUIInternalUpdater.updateRoot(JavaScriptBootstrapUI.java:427)
> ~[flow-server-23.3.4.jar:23.3.4]  at
> com.vaadin.flow.component.internal.UIInternals.showRouteTarget(UIInternals.java:769)
> ~[flow-server-23.3.4.jar:23.3.4]  at
> com.vaadin.flow.router.internal.AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.handle(AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.java:231)
> ~[flow-server-23.3.4.jar:23.3.4]  at
> com.vaadin.flow.component.internal.JavaScriptNavigationStateRenderer.handle(JavaScriptNavigationStateRenderer.java:78)
> ~[flow-server-23.3.4.jar:23.3.4]  at
> com.vaadin.flow.component.internal.JavaScriptBootstrapUI.handleNavigation(JavaScriptBootstrapUI.java:322)
> ~[flow-server-23.3.4.jar:23.3.4]  at
> com.vaadin.flow.component.internal.JavaScriptBootstrapUI.renderViewForRoute(JavaScriptBootstrapUI.java:285)
> ~[flow-server-23.3.4.jar:23.3.4]  at
> com.vaadin.flow.component.internal.JavaScriptBootstrapUI.connectClient(JavaScriptBootstrapUI.java:151)
> ~[flow-server-23.3.4.jar:23.3.4]  at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
> at
> com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.rpc.PublishedServerEventHandlerRpcHandler.invokeMethod(PublishedServerEventHandlerRpcHandler.java:222)
> ~[flow-server-23.3.4.jar:23.3.4]  at
> com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.rpc.PublishedServerEventHandlerRpcHandler.invokeMethod(PublishedServerEventHandlerRpcHandler.java:199)
> ~[flow-server-23.3.4.jar:23.3.4]  at
> com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.rpc.PublishedServerEventHandlerRpcHandler.invokeMethod(PublishedServerEventHandlerRpcHandler.java:149)
> ~[flow-server-23.3.4.jar:23.3.4]  at
> com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.rpc.PublishedServerEventHandlerRpcHandler.handleNode(PublishedServerEventHandlerRpcHandler.java:132)
> ~[flow-server-23.3.4.jar:23.3.4]  at
> com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.rpc.AbstractRpcInvocationHandler.handle(AbstractRpcInvocationHandler.java:75)
> ~[flow-server-23.3.4.jar:23.3.4]  at
> com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocationData(ServerRpcHandler.java:438)
> ~[flow-server-23.3.4.jar:23.3.4]  at
> com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.lambda$handleInvocations$1(ServerRpcHandler.java:419)
> ~[flow-server-23.3.4.jar:23.3.4]  at
> java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511) ~[na:na]
> at
> com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocations(ServerRpcHandler.java:419)
> ~[flow-server-23.3.4.jar:23.3.4]  at
> com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:320)
> ~[flow-server-23.3.4.jar:23.3.4]  at
> com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:115)
> ~[flow-server-23.3.4.jar:23.3.4]  at
> com.vaadin.flow.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:40)
> ~[flow-server-23.3.4.jar:23.3.4]  at
> com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1564)
> ~[flow-server-23.3.4.jar:23.3.4]  at
> com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:369)
> ~[flow-server-23.3.4.jar:23.3.4]  at
> com.vaadin.flow.spring.SpringServlet.service(SpringServlet.java:106)
> ~[vaadin-spring-23.3.4.jar:na]    at
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:596)
> ~[servlet-api.jar:4.0.FR]     at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
> ~[catalina.jar:9.0.72]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
> ~[catalina.jar:9.0.72]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:661)
> ~[catalina.jar:9.0.72]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:425)
> ~[catalina.jar:9.0.72]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:330)
> ~[catalina.jar:9.0.72]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:294)
> ~[catalina.jar:9.0.72]    at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletForwardingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletForwardingController.java:141)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]    at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]    at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:51)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]    at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1071)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]    at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:964)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]    at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]    at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]    at
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:528)
> ~[servlet-api.jar:4.0.FR]     at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]    at
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:596)
> ~[servlet-api.jar:4.0.FR]     at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
> ~[catalina.jar:9.0.72]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
> ~[catalina.jar:9.0.72]    at
> org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
> ~[tomcat-websocket.jar:9.0.72]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
> ~[catalina.jar:9.0.72]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
> ~[catalina.jar:9.0.72]    at
> org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]   at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
> ~[catalina.jar:9.0.72]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
> ~[catalina.jar:9.0.72]    at
> org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]   at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
> ~[catalina.jar:9.0.72]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
> ~[catalina.jar:9.0.72]    at
> org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:126)
> ~[spring-boot-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]    at
> org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:64)
> ~[spring-boot-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]    at
> org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:101)
> ~[spring-boot-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]    at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]   at
> org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:119)
> ~[spring-boot-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
> ~[catalina.jar:9.0.72]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
> ~[catalina.jar:9.0.72]    at
> org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]   at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
> ~[catalina.jar:9.0.72]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
> ~[catalina.jar:9.0.72]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)
> ~[catalina.jar:9.0.72]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
> ~[catalina.jar:9.0.72]    at
> org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:492)
> ~[catalina.jar:9.0.72]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:130)
> ~[catalina.jar:9.0.72]    at
> org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
> ~[catalina.jar:9.0.72]    at
> org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:673)
> ~[catalina.jar:9.0.72]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
> ~[catalina.jar:9.0.72]    at
> org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
> ~[catalina.jar:9.0.72]    at
> org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
> ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.72]   at
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
> ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.72]   at
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:926)
> ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.72]   at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1791)
> ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.72]   at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
> ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.72]   at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
> ~[tomcat-util.jar:9.0.72]     at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
> ~[tomcat-util.jar:9.0.72]     at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
> ~[tomcat-util.jar:9.0.72]     at
> java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]

As there is no reference to my code at all in the stack trace, I don't know where even to start looking. I did have this exception in the past, but after I placed @PreserveOnRefresh into my main layout it was gone. Now it is back and I have no idea what is causing it and how to fix it.
Here is the code for my main layout:

```
@PageTitle("Энциклопедия")
@Route(value = "")
@PreserveOnRefresh
public class EncyclopediaMainLayout extends VerticalLayout {

   private final  HeaderLayout header;
   private final  TableLayout table;

   public EncyclopediaMainLayout(@Autowired HeaderLayout hdr, @Autowired TableLayout tbl) {
      this.header = hdr;
      this.table = tbl;
      add(header, table);
   }    
}
```

I do have a suspicion that it somehow related to more than a single session accessing this page, but I am not sure. Anyway web application shall allow multiple sessions.
Also I am not moving any nodes in my code.
Please do help me to find the fix for this problem.

I did check [Can't move a node from one state tree to another. If this is intentional, first remove the node from its current state tree by calling removeFromTree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72819037/cant-move-a-node-from-one-state-tree-to-another-if-this-is-intentional-first) and went through all my code:

- I do not have any singleton or static components.
  The only statics I have there some integer and String constants and something like this:

  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ReviewPanel.class);

  or

  private static final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

I don't think those can cause such exception, but if it does, please do tell me and I will remove all statics.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72819037/cant-move-a-node-from-one-state-tree-to-another-if-this-is-intentional-first

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't move a node from one state tree to another. If this is intentional, first remove the node from its current state tree by calling removeFromTree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72819037/cant-move-a-node-from-one-state-tree-to-another-if-this-is-intentional-first)

Comment: I do not have any Vaadin components defined as static or singleton. All my Spring beans are defined with @Scope("prototype") annotation. How can I find what is causing this exception? Vaadin diagnostic shall specify offending component, but unfortunately it is not doing that.

Comment: I did make some changes to my app, fixing little glitch, and this very same exception appears within a single session, just when I am making a page refresh.
I do repeat: There is not a single static or singleton component in the whole application.
How can I find the cause of this exception? Please do help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did try many things and finally I got the solution.
When I annotated my main layout with @PreserveOnRefresh it is no longer throwing this exception.
I am sure that it is not the best solution but, until Vaadin team improve their diagnostics that will help identify component that is causing this exception, I can't do anything better.