# Vaadin Update Component content when variable change on the application

Tags: spring-boot, vaadin

I am building a Vaadin Spring Boot application. I want to update a component of this view asynchronously through a simple scheduler service.

```
@Service
@EnableScheduling
public class CounterUpdater {
  private int counterValue = 0;

  @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5_000) 
  public void updateCounter() {
    counterValue++;
    System.out.println("Counter updated to:"+counterValue);
 }
}
```

In my Vaadin View the component is a simple label which needs to be kept updated according to counterValue.

```
counterLabel = new Label("Counter:"); // I create the component
add(counterLabel); // I add it to the view.
[...]

 // Asynchronous method to update the label
 public void setCounterValue(int value) {
      getUI().get().access(new Command() {
          @Override
          public void execute() {
              counterLabel.setText("Counter: " + counterValue);
          }
      });
```

I tried many ways so far, the more promising being a constructor on the service:

```
public CounterUpdater(@Autowired EmptyView counterView) {
    this.counterView = counterView;
}
```

That allows me to run this on the scheduler.
`counterView.setCounterValue(counterValue);`

To have this to work I had to add a @Constructor annotation to the view, so that the custom constructor doesn’t give me issue, but if I reload the page it gives me a:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't move a node from one state tree to another. If this is intentional, first remove the node from its current state tree by calling removeFromTree
```

Anyway this @Controller annotation give me other issues. I’d like to know which is the best practice to have a View Component automatically updated when some object changes on the page without the user to reload the page. Maybe the View need to poll the value instead of the service push it? Maybe I need to use some plugin or the collaborative feature? This should be simple but I am struggling already two days on this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't move a node from one state tree to another. If this is intentional, first remove the node from its current state tree by calling removeFromTree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72819037/cant-move-a-node-from-one-state-tree-to-another-if-this-is-intentional-first)

Comment: Thank you, this is useful, demonstrates that "Vaadin does not allow sharing components.". So my approach is not correct. So the question is still:  "which is the best practice to have a View Component automatically updated when some object changes on the page without the user to reload the page"

Comment: Best to what metric? The common one is to use some sort of pub/sub - whether this the one from vaadin, spring, thirdparty or external depends on the usecase.